# How I can compare the LINQ result?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find a method to compare the element inside LINQ result

This is the LINQ code

```
var sets =
         from a in patient.AsParallel()
         from b in patient.AsParallel()
         from c in patient.AsParallel()
         from d in patient.AsParallel()



where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum
select new { a, b, c, d };

var sets1 =
                 from a in patient1.AsParallel()
                 from b in patient1.AsParallel()
                 from c in patient1.AsParallel()
                 from d in patient1.AsParallel()
select new { a, b, c, d };
```

and this code I used it to compare but every time give me false

```
 if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(sets, sets1) == true)
```

Any suggestion ?

// update as Jani's Answer

```
public class Result
    {
        public ACVsize5 a { get; set; }
        public ACVsize5 b { get; set; }
        public ACVsize5 c { get; set; }
        public ACVsize5 d { get; set; }


}

public override Boolean Equals(Result other)
        {
            return other.a.date.ToString() == a.date.ToString() && other.a.RaId.ToString() == a.RaId.ToString() && other.b.date.ToString() == b.date.ToString() && other.b.RaId.ToString() == b.RaId.ToString() && other.c.date.ToString() == c.date.ToString() && other.c.RaId.ToString() == c.RaId.ToString() && other.d.date.ToString() == d.date.ToString() && other.d.RaId.ToString() == d.RaId.ToString();
        }

var sets =
             from a in patient
             from b in patient
             from c in patient
             from d in patient
where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum              

select new Result { a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d };
var sets1 =
             from t in patient1
             from y in patient1
             from u in patient1
             from p in patient1
where t.VisitNum < y.VisitNum && y.VisitNum < u.VisitNum && u.VisitNum < p.VisitNum 
             select new Result { a = t, b = y, c = u, d = p };
```

but I got error on override methods

```
//Error 1 no suitable method found to override
```

Comment: i guess they both are empty..

Comment: Off topic, but FYI - this is a really bad way of getting all combinations for `a < b < c < d`. It is very inefficient. You should sort once and then you can say that for indices `i,j,k,l` that are `i < j < k < l`, the matching elements are a combination.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ you r right the collection are empty

Comment: You really didn't check their content..?

Comment: @Yorye Nathan  I did not get what you mean Can you explain more ?

Comment: I'm saying that if you have, for example, `7, 2, 1, 5, 9, 3`, so I understand that you want to get `{1,2,3,5},{1,2,3,7},{1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,7},{2,3,5,9},{3,5,7,9}`, not necessarily in that order. To do that, it'd be much faster to sort the elements first and work with `1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9`.

Comment: @Wimaxmax Did you understand what I've written?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Actully you are trying to compare two different anonymous classes which has been generated under the hood (`System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#1>'` and `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'`).</strike>

I was wrong and as stated by @Allon, there will be generated just one class for the same structure.

Whenever you use the select new in a Linq query without specifying the class name before open bracket, an anonymous class will be generated under the hood which you can see it by tools like [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/).

<strike>Another important point is that when you compare objects of a type which you declared(not part of .NET Framework Library), they will be compared by their references not by their content.
Thus you must define your own implementation of equality, by overriding the Equals method.</strike>

That's not the case for anonymous classes cause the compiler will generate those methods for them.

To learn more:
[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx),
[2](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/02/16/c.net-little-wonders-the-sequenceequal-method.aspx)

<strike>Create a simple class (named result for example) and make the result of query of that type.
Then `override` the `Equals` method of the class and use the `SequenceEqual`.
everything will be right.</strike>

```
public Class Result{
  public string a {get;set}
  public string b {get;set}
  public string c {get;set}
  public string d {get;set}
  //this is a short incomplete version of equals implementation
  //consult other questions to learn more about equality
  public override boolean Equals(Result other)
  { return other.a == a && other.b == b && other.c == c && other.d == d}
}

//you must add another order by clause to query so that both of them have the same order
var sets =
     (from a in patient.AsParallel()
     from b in patient.AsParallel()
     from c in patient.AsParallel()
     from d in patient.AsParallel()
     where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum
     select new Result{ a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d }).AsEnumerable();
var sets1 =
     (from a in patient1.AsParallel()
     from b in patient1.AsParallel()
     from c in patient1.AsParallel()
     from d in patient1.AsParallel()
     select new Result{ a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d }).AsEnumerable();
//Now it would be right
if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(sets, sets1))
{
   //do your stuff
}
```

You just need to ensure that those sequences have the same order.

Comment: I have made what you suggest but I got this error Error 4The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I correct the error but now every time give me false  I do not know why even I am sure it is true

Comment: They must have the same order

Comment: what is the type here in this code List<ACVsize5> patient = new List<ACVsize5>();  LISt or ACVsize5 ?

Comment: Actually both of them combined will generate a new generic type which is `List<ACVsize5>`, but they solely are types also.

Comment: a,b,c,d are elements on this  public List<ACVsize5> patient = new List<ACVsize5>(); so when i need to define the class for Result what type should I use ?

Comment: What do you mean by your first statement?? You need it to make compiler not generate anonymous class for Linq query result

Comment: I'm sorry Jani, but what you claim is simply incorrect. If you create two anonymous types in two different places in your code that have the same member names, types and order, the compiler will only generate a single type, so they will both be of the same type. Otherwise using `.SequenceEqual()` wouldn't even compile since it cannot compare two sequences of different types (both `IEnumerable<T>` are of the same `T`). Also, anonymous types automatically have a content-based `.Equals()` method override generated, so they are in fact compared by their content, not reference (`Tuple`s too).

Comment: @AllonGuralnek How i compare them now like this `if(sets.Equals(sets1)==true)` I tried it but every time give me false !!

Comment: You've also overridden Equals without overriding GetHashCode, and the SequenceEquals will still only hold if the source sequence is empty.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek Thanks, I'll check it, you're right and I was almost completely wrong, stuff that I wrote just might be helpful for learning if updated to reflect the correct implementation.

Comment: @Wimaxmax For debugging add a .ToList() call to the end of query instead of .AsEnumerable, such that the queries will be executed immediately and values will be avaialbe for view in debugger, then check the contents of set and set1.

Comment: SO that I can use it like this `if(sets.Equals(sets1)==true)` ?

Comment: Did you check out the values in debug mode?

Comment: Do u mean in Windows form ? I printed it out the result it is in the same order

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20487/discussion-between-jani-and-wimaxmax)

Answer (score 0):

After I tried many soluton I made two foreach inside each other  to compare the element inside the sets  but this solutotion is very bad and take long time to compare a huge data